# pptx-python: find table height dynamically after adding text

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I want to find the height of the table dynamically, so that whenever the table's height reaches a specific number, I can create another slide and split the table. Because number of text in cell varies, the height will be different for each time the code is run.

Is it possible to do it in pptx-python?

Answer (score 0):

No. "Stretched" table cell heights and the resulting overall table height turns out to be a rendering concern and those values are not recorded in the `.pptx` file.

A row or cell can have a *minimum* height that is set in the file, but once the cell gets more text than it can display it will automatically grow beyond that minimum and the PowerPoint renderer is the one to do that. It does not record the value it ends up with.

One way to approximate the rendered dimensions of a table cell is to render the the text yourself in some sort of graphical environment and see how big it gets. That value will depend on the font type-face and point-size, so you'll need to know those. Any way you go about it will be approximate; there are a lot of small complicating factors and even one renderer like OpenOffice might not always render exactly like another, say PowerPoint or Google Docs. For example, there may also be *column width* adjustment rules that PowerPoint uses to help accommodate a heavily populated cell, not just making the cell taller.

I've heard of at least one developer having reasonable results using wxPython as a rendering environment in which to approximate PowerPoint's rendering behavior, but I believe that was for a single textbox. Doing the same for a table is potentially much more complex.

Another route might be to use VBA to drive an actually running instance of PowerPoint. That may give access to the rendered size of the table.